Ubuntu 24.04 Network icon missing after upgrade
I upgraded Ubuntu Desktop to 24.04 LTS. Prior to that upgrade there was an icon in the upper right of the screen that gave me networking details. That is now missing. Is there a way to restore it?

Is the network active, but just no icon? If so, perhaps Network icon disappeared or Running Xubuntu, the network icon is missing and can't get it back will help.

The network connection is working fine. It is just the networking icon is missing from the upper right.

This may not be related to the Ubuntu upgrade. I upgrades a 2nd system (identical hardware) and the network icon stayed available. That points to operator error. But I have no idea what I did.

From searching, as far as I can tell with 24.04 LTS there is no user setting to select if the GNOME System Menu displays the network status icon or not. Instead the System Menu uses the Network Manager to determine the network status icon. On the affected PC what does nmcli device show report as the GENERAL.STATE for the network connection?

I had the same problem when upgrading from Kubuntu 22.04 jammy to Kubuntu 24.04 noble. The networking icon disappeared.
During upgrade I saw that my networks were migrated to netplan. I played around with it some time ago during before upgrading.
However: I fixed the problem by installing plasma-nm as suggested on wiki.ubuntuusers.de
# Kubuntu 24.04:
sudo apt install plasma-nm

# Ubuntu 24.04: (not tested by me)
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome 

